# Android View Binding set Custom Generated package name

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions, android-viewbinding

Default android generate (my package name is `com.exaple`) and it generate `com.example.databinding.Activity`

I have lots of classes that reference `com.example.sample.databinding.Activity`
so i have to change `com.example` to `com.example.sample` to all my viewBinding
it can be possible to change view binding configuration to generate viewBinding in `com.exaple.sample` package name ?

I googled but nothing will helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly your build.gradle contains a namespace, you can change it to:
`namespace 'com.example.example'` (in the android block), and after that if you rebuild your project (and maybe restart the IDE, generating the binding classes sometimes can be annoying) should result in the desired behaviour